# What are ways to measure carbon fixation of microalgae?

Tags: lab-techniques, research-tools

So I am conducting a very simple experiment about microalgaes, particularly their biofixation of carbon dioxide. In a small compartment, where microalgaes are suspended in water with an air pump that supplies carbon dioxide for growth and development.

1. What are possible techniques to measure the biofixation rate that utilizes less highly specialized equipment as much as possible?
2. Is it also possible to conduct gravimetric analysis to measure biofixation?